# MySQL - Loop while

Tags: mysql

I´ve been asked to create a report which shows how many employees are working in different departments during the last trailing 12 months (MM-YYYY).

I need to print out every single month for every combination of Department, Role_Name and Employee_Code.

I want to print out results that look like this:
(Assuming that employee 234 joined the company on Sept 15 as a Jr Consultant in the BSG department, was then promoted to consultant in Jan 16 and then changed department in Apr 16)

```
Date    Department Role_Name    Employee_Code
Jun 16  CIN        Consultant   234
Mai 16  CIN        Consultant   234
Apr 16  CIN        Consultant   234
Mrz 16  BSG        Consultant   234
Feb 16  BSG        Consultant   234
Jan 16  BSG        Consultant   234
Dez 15  BSG       Jr Consultant 234
Nov 15  BSG       Jr Consultant 234
Okt 15  BSG       Jr Consultant 234
Sep 15  BSG       Jr Consultant 234
```

Attached my code.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS WhileLoop;
PROCEDURE WhileLoop()

BEGIN
  DECLARE date.date char;

  WhileLoop : Loop  

    IF (date.date < date_format(prs.rpr_end_dt,'%Y-%m')) THEN
      LEAVE WhileLoop;
    END IF;

    SET date.date = date.date;
  END LOOP WhileLoop; 
END;


SELECT
date.date
,prs.EMPLOYEE_ID
,prs.DEPARTMENT
,prs.ROLE_NAME
   ,CASE
        WHEN prs_person_end_dt < curdate() THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END as 'Still with Company?'

    ,CASE
        WHEN prs_person_end_dt < curdate() THEN concat(month(prs_person_end_dt), ' - ', year(prs_person_end_dt))
        ELSE ''
    END as QuitDate

FROM
   dim_prs_person prs

        /*Used for getting the month/year*/
    inner join (
        select date_format(dys_date,'%Y-%m') as date
        from lkp_dys_days
        group by date_format(dys_date,'%Y-%m')
        ) date on date_format(prs.rpr_start_dt,'%Y-%m') = date.date


/*WHERE
date.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 12  MONTH ) AND CURDATE()*/

ORDER BY
    prs.PMA_PERSON_CODE
    ,date.date;
```

The results currently look like this:

```
Date     Employee_code  Department  Role_Name   Still with Company? QuitDate
2015-12     ABNA             OFF    Werkstudent         Quit         Mai 16
2013-02     ADMN             OFF    Werkstudent     
2013-02     ADMN             ECO    Consultant      
2014-08     ADMN             OFF    External Partner        
2007-09     ALDE             ECN    Consultant          Quit          Jun 12
2013-04     BEGD             CIN    Consultant      
2015-10     LAUE             BSO    Werkstudent         Quit          Jan 16
2012-10     PORE             CIN    Praktikant      
2013-01     PORE             CIN    Junior Consultant       
2014-07     PORE             BPN    Consultant
```

As you can see, all months are currently NOT repeated for each employee code, department and role name. For example, for the first Employee (ABNA), I want a print of every single month until May 16, in which month the person quit.

This is an example of the lkp_dys_days table:

```
DYS_MONTH   DYS_YEAR    DYS_DATE
7            2004       01.07.2004
7            2004       02.07.2004
7            2004       03.07.2004
7            2004       04.07.2004
7            2004       05.07.2004
```

This is an example of the dim_prs_person table:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID PRS_PERSON_START_DT PRS_PERSON_END_DT   DEPARTMENT  ROLE_NAME
BODA          01.07.2004       30.06.2007            OFF    Jr Consultant
BODA          01.07.2007       31.12.2099            OFF    Consultant
MELE          01.07.2004       30.06.2007            CIN    Consultant
MELE          01.07.2007       31.07.2009            BSD    Sr Consultant
OIDA          01.10.2004       30.09.2008            CIN    Consultant
EMED          01.11.2004       30.11.2006            CIN    Sr Consultant
DKEL          02.11.2004       30.09.2009            BSD    Werkstudent
DHJE          01.12.2004       30.05.2016            BSD    Jr Consultant
DHEH          24.01.2005       23.05.2005            ECO    Jr Consultant
MEINE         01.04.2005       31.08.2007            TDE    Consultant
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure the result fits your description (what does "Consultant" and "Jr Consultant" mean in your result when you want the total number of workers in a department per month?). You don't need a loop, you need a `group by` and `sum()` or `count()`. And you should add your table descriptions/some example data.

Comment: I edited everything to make the question clearer. I´m pretty sure that sum(), count() and group by () will not be enough to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your table `lkp_dys_days` correctly as a list of all existing days (you need something like that), you can use

```
select concat(d.dys_year, '-', lpad(d.dys_month, 2, '0')) as date,
  prs.DEPARTMENT,
  prs.ROLE_NAME,
  prs.EMPLOYEE_ID
from dim_prs_person prs
join lkp_dys_days d
on prs.rpr_start_dt <= d.dys_date 
   and prs.prs_person_end_dt >= d.dys_date
where d.dysdate > date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
      and d.dys_date <= curdate()
group by d.dys_year, d.dys_month, prs.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
         prs.PRS_PERSON_START_DT, prs.DEPARTMENT, prs.ROLE_NAME
order by d.dys_year desc, d.dys_month desc,
         prs.EMPLOYEE_ID, prs.PRS_PERSON_START_DT;
```

If you want to show the whole year even if the person wasn't there yet, you can use a `right outer join` instead of the `join`.

Comment: This is ALMOST perfect, great job!
However, if the person changes roles or departments, instead of being shown 12 times, the person is shown then 24 times. The code needs to check the dim_prs_person table for the PRS_PERSON_END_DT for the position name

Comment: I managed to join the tables correctly and get hte right result, thanks!

Comment: @Ayuanaur I couldnt test it, but it shouldn't show all month twice, just the month of a change (if there is an overlap - it wasn't clear if you need a special handling). How did you change the code, I can edit in the answer (or if you have enough points, you can do it too).